# No operator = match these operands c++ even though said operator has been overloaded

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a multiplication for my vector class and my matrix class.

```
Vector2f Matrix3x3::operator * (Vector2f & v) {
    float vx = e11 * v.x + e21 * v.y + e31;
    float vy = e12 * v.x + e22 * v.y + e32;
    return Vector2f(vx, vy);
}
```

When a matrix multiplies with a vector it should return a vector. So I try to set the result to an already created vector object.

```
Vector2f d(12, 12);
Matrix3x3 m = translationMatrix(transX, transY);
d = m * d;
```

VS keeps underlining my "=" and says that no operators = match these operands, operands type are Vector2f and Vector2f. Even though I already overload assignment operator in Vector2f class

```
Vector2f & Vector2f::operator = (Vector2f & V) { 
    x = V.x;
    y = V.y;
    return *this;
}
```

I dont even know where I am wrong. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: You might want to consider using a move-assignment operator if your compiler supports using move semantics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Matrix3x3::operator *` returns by value, which means the object returned by `m * d` is a temporary, which can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const (i.e. `Vector2f &`); but it can be bound to lvalue-reference to const (i.e. `const Vector2f &`).

To solve the issue you chould change the parameter type of `operator=` to `const Vector2f &`, and you should do this also because the argument is supposed to be not modified inside `operator=`.

```
Vector2f & Vector2f::operator = (const Vector2f & V) { 
    x = V.x;
    y = V.y;
    return *this;
}
```